# Why does zero to non-zero in storage take higher gas?

Tags: storage, gas-price, eip

According to EIP-1087 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1087 , it take 20,000 gas to set a slot from 0 to non-zero with SSTORE while it takes only 5000 gas for any other change. Why does 0 to non-0 change take higher gas than any other change?

Answer (score 7):

This is a form of state or storage rent.

When you change a state slot from 0 (the default) to non-0, you are increasing the size of the overall state data. The overall blockchain data - the "world state" - is 256-bits bigger than it was, and you are paying for that privilege.

In the real world, this means you are storing extra data on the HDDs/SSDs of anyone running a full or archive node.

If you're only changing the data from a non-0 value to another non-0 value, you are not increasing the size of the data, and not asking everyone running a node to increase the use of their storage hardware.

Comment: When does such an operation occur exactly? Like is it possible that I do a USDC or USDT `transfer`, and then suddenly I need to pay 5000 or 20000 extra gas because my transfer happens to cause the need for 256 extra bits? Or can I completely control this beforehand?

Comment: An example of incurring the additional gas would be if you were transferring to an address that doesn't currently have a token balance (i.e. implicitly `0`). So if you know the token balance of your recipient in advance it would give you an idea of whether this additional gas would be required or not.

Comment: I see. And do you happen to know if this `SSTORE` operation always costs `20000` gas when the recipient's value goes from `0` to non-zero? Or is it only the first time? (I know some other tokens where this is only a 1-time payment). In other words, would it be beneficial for me if the recipient always kept a tiny amount of that ERC-20 token so I wouldn't have to pay those fees? :)

Comment: That's a good question. I believe for ERC20 tokens this cost would be incurred each time. So if a user had a balance, but spent all their tokens resulting in a `0` balance, the next time they received any tokens you'd be taking a new storage slot again. (Because of how mappings work.)

Comment: Note that this is the gas "cost" (i.e. amount of work being done), not the actual price of the operation in ETH/Gwei. The price you pay will depend on what you want to pay for each unit of gas (i.e. work), which can theoretically be very low (even 0-priced transactions used to go through eventually). Given the complexity of some token contracts, I don't think `20000` gas is something to try to optimise out. :-)

Comment: (This might be useful when looking at other parts of your contract -> https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md#a7-sstore)

Comment: Horrock Thanks, I actually made a question on this, turns out you indeed pay 20000 each time your destination spends everything and then receives something again: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/149700/would-always-keeping-a-non-zero-amount-of-every-relevant-erc-20-token-lower-tran .

Comment: Aha, that's a good answer to your question :-) Glad you figured it out!