# The second time I call the same function with the same parameters, costs 21.600 gas less. Why?

Tags: gas

I'm calling a function of one of my contracts with the same parameters twice in a row (locally). The gas spent by the first transaction is `178,310`, while the gas spent by the second transaction is only `156,710`.

`let result = await instance.myFunction(amount,list,rates,tokens,{from:accounts[1],value:web3.utils.toWei("20","ether")})`

The difference is exactly `21,600` gas, I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the gas cost of a value transfer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The number just happens to be similar to the minimum transaction cost of 21000, it's not related to that.

There are various things that may make a second call have different gas cost. The most typical one is storage of data: changing a value of a previously non-set variable to non-zero costs more than setting it again from non-zero to non-zero. Here's some more information about that: [Why does zero to non-zero in storage take higher gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/why-does-zero-to-non-zero-in-storage-take-higher-gas)

Otherwise, there may be a bunch of reasons: for example different code paths based on whether some data is already stored or not, or even calls to external contracts.

Comment: Thanks Lauri. As an indication, my code doesn't modify any storage and always follow the same flow (since I call it immediately after the first call with the same parameters, and no storage is modified). I'm wondering, could it be because the first call is the first call EVER to any function on the contract and solidity does some kind of set up, maybe related to initializing the constructor (my contract does initialize a couple storage variables in the constructor) or something like that? Thanks again

Comment: The constructor is only called when the contract is deployed, so it's not related to that. But impossible to say what the reason is without seeing the code.