# Why do these two Ethereum transactions have different gas usages? Can't explain it from the GETH EVM debug traces

Tags: solidity, gas

Two USDC transfers in the same block, both between non-contract addresses. Both call the same smart contract function `transfer()` but used very different gas. Some differences I can explain (see below) but others I can't.

- tx1. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x27f9973f560584df2d3abdd8d55fdefe598a0d3d1279dc9380476cb6f60a2963
- tx2. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x250b59352747b186e2cbe17f59048e9adaac9556d50b9a598d4a8356f04b800d

Gas usage for tx1 is 65625 and for tx2 is 43725. That's a difference of 21900.

Both transactions transfer between non-contract addresses.

GETH debug traces:

- tx1. https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x27f9973f560584df2d3abdd8d55fdefe598a0d3d1279dc9380476cb6f60a2963
- tx2. https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x250b59352747b186e2cbe17f59048e9adaac9556d50b9a598d4a8356f04b800d

1. Before **step [1]**, the remaining gas (the `Gas` column) is `GasLimit - 21605` (where I recall that the 21605 comes from the minimum 21600 plus 5 gas from somewhere else I forgot). So in the GETH debug trace tx1 starts with 66163-21605=44558 gas and tx2 starts with 73188-21605=51583. So far so good.
2. At **step [122]** when executing DELEGATECALL tx1 used 39328 gas and tx2 used 46243 gas. This accounts for -6915 of the difference.
3. At **step [435]** when executing SSTORE tx1 used 20000 and tx2 used 2900. This accounts for 17100 of the difference. The yellow paper says SSTORE uses 20000 gas when the storage value is set to non-zero from zero (this is the 2nd SSTORE call, and given it goes from 0 to >0 then I take it it's the destination address that is receiving funds).

The above are the only two differences in `GasCost`, which account for 17100-6915=10185 so they do not explain the full difference of 21900 gas. There is still 11715 gas difference that remains unexplained.

Questions:

- Why does DELEGATECALL use different gas at step [122]?
- Can someone explain where the rest of the gas usage difference of 11715 gas comes from?

EDIT: See the comments below from @Nulik regarding gas refund, which is the main culprit (and doesn't show in the VM opcode trace). @Nulik please post an answer so I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: the first link to etherscan is broken, tx hash invalid error shows up

Comment: since the cost of a CALL (delegate, static, etc) depends on current memory usage, most likely the difference is due to different memory size.

Comment: Links working now. As for memory size, I'm not sure. It should be visible in the VM trace, shouldn't it? Only the DELEGATECALL show different gas used. The full difference of gas used is still not explained.

Comment: as for memory, it does add the cost for memory size upon any `Call()` opcode (check it here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/01808421e20ba9d19c029b64fcda841df77c9aff/core/vm/gas_table.go#L392 , calculating gas is a complicated topic, you can see it yourself in this source code I am linking, specially about SSTORE, it is a big mess, so explaining gas difference can take you whole day. I wouldn't spend time on it

Comment: @Nulik I did believe you the first time, and it explains why DELEGATECALL uses different gas in the two txs. What I was saying is that there is still 11715 gas difference that remains unexplained, and the VM trace doesn't show it. Shouldn't the VM trace show all gas used? Where does the 11715 gas difference come from? I'd like to understand it, even if qualitatively.

Comment: ahhh! maybe you spotted the gas refund effect. if the VM trace doesn't show some gas, then it must be because of gas refund for releasing storage. this is done at the end of the transaction (here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/01808421e20ba9d19c029b64fcda841df77c9aff/core/state_transition.go#L368 )  after transaction ends, and if it was successful, the gas is refunded at this line: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/01808421e20ba9d19c029b64fcda841df77c9aff/core/state_transition.go#L339

Comment: Thanks again. I suspected there might be gas refund involved. I can see st.gas increasing when a refund is issued, and I can understand why this wouldn't show in the EVM trace because there is no opcode execution for it, but shouldn't it be reported somewhere so that tx accounting is guaranteed completeness? Feels dissatisfying to just assume that whatever is outside the EVM must be refunded gas, especially if there could be multiple calls to `refundGas()`. Feels like this should be part of some accounting trace, or otherwise the full execution of a tx cannot be explained nor reproduced.

Comment: I noticed that neither `refundGas()` nor any functions in the call tree trigger any accounting events. This means there is no way to fully explain or reproduce a tx execution -- i.e. if I didn't have two txs to compare and I was looking at just one tx, I would have no idea whether there was any gas refund issued or not, or how much was it ... unless I'm missing something.

In any case, you should post an answer so I can upvote it @Nulik

Comment: @Normadize have you tried a gas profiler like Tenderly one? iirc, gas refund is explicitly showed

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth thanks for that, I didn't know that tool. It's quite neat too. Indeed it shows a gas refund of 11825 gas: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x250b59352747b186e2cbe17f59048e9adaac9556d50b9a598d4a8356f04b800d/gas-usage ... whereas the other tx has no gas refund.  The refund is 110 gas larger than the total difference, so there is still -110 gas difference to explain (I'll dig deeper later) but the bulk is now clear.

Comment: @Normadize Hey, I was wondering, does this mean that there is a hard limit on the range of how much gas 2 USDC transactions can differ? I know of `SSTORE` costing 20k gas, and I know every byte used to encode the "value" (amount of ERC-20 to send) costs 16 gas. Would you know of other calls that would increase your `65625` value? I'm trying to find the absolute worst case :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for the gas cost not being the same would be that one account did not have any usdc before the transaction and the other already had some. It cost more gas to set a 0 value to non zero than non zero to non zero.

For instance. The new account does not have his address written in the usdc balance mapping. So the contract would have to record the address and set the balance. The other account already have is address written and we just updated the balance.

See;
[Why does zero to non-zero in storage take higher gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/why-does-zero-to-non-zero-in-storage-take-higher-gas)

Comment: I wonder if you read the full post, as I already identified and discussed the SSTORE difference