# Would always keeping a non-zero amount of every relevant ERC-20 token lower transaction costs over time?

Tags: erc-20, gas, gas-estimate

There is a Smart Contract call called `SSTORE` (See ETH Yellow Paper page 27: https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

It costs **20000** gas if a zero byte is set to a non-zero byte.
It costs **5000** gas if a non-zero byte is set to another non-zero byte.

Here are 2 transactions where one does, and the other one doesn't pay 20000:

- 63,221 gas: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3fe51993e9840baa36089a930303126848054ee4e574af26e421b51298dd97be
- 41,309 gas: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9ace5449eb6e06869811160970ae80df6c78303996f37aaef7ed48bbf55d6b18

So then what if I adopt a policy that me and those people I interact with, must always keep at least 1 (in lowest units) of every of the ERC-20 tokens that are relevant to us? If I understand this correctly it would mean that nobody would ever have to pay 20000 gas anymore for the `SSTORE` operation.

I could keep 0.000001 `USDT` / `USDC`, and 0.000000000000000001 `LINK`, and then if someone would send me either of those tokens, they'd always have to pay only 5000 gas for the `SSTORE` operation.

Am I correct in thinking this, or am I missing something? Is this already being considered or implemented in the wild?

### Related posts

- [Why does zero to non-zero in storage take higher gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/why-does-zero-to-non-zero-in-storage-take-higher-gas)
- [Why do these two Ethereum transactions have different gas usages? Can't explain it from the GETH EVM debug traces](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/141687/why-do-these-two-ethereum-transactions-have-different-gas-usages-cant-explain?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Calculate transaction costs for storing data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/calculate-transaction-costs-for-storing-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, by keeping at least one wei of ERC20 tokens you can save on gas fees in the long run. This is a common tactic used by MEV bots, and you can find MEV bots in the wild that hold 1 wei of many ERC20 tokens.

[Here](https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0x6b75d8AF000000e20B7a7DDf000Ba900b4009A80) is an MEV bot with over 3,000 ERC20 tokens. You can find more on https://eigenphi.io/.

Also, by holding one wei of all ERC20 tokens you interact with, you may be eligible for airdrops and other holder benefits in the future.